# Удалить строку указанную в столбце из другого столбца без учёта регистра

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо удалить в наименовании производителя, который указан в разном регистре, несколько раз и в скобках.

После этого, уже к чистому наименованию в конец добавить производителя из соседнего столбца.

У меня такой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re 

df = pd.read_excel("In\\Sample.xlsx")
df.loc[:, 'Наименование'] = [re.sub('\s*\(\s*\)', '', n.replace(a, ''), flags=re.I).strip() 
                                                 for a, n in zip(df.Производитель, df.Наименование)]
df.Наименование  = df.Наименование + " " + df.Производитель
```

Он ошибочный - вырезается только ровно в том написании, как он включен в столбец "Производитель".:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть разница - в полном варианте файла почти 700 000 строк. Если есть оптимальное решение перебирать строки быстрее - буду рад выслушать.

[Пример данных](https://yadi.sk/i/XgJc6IoHQhonbw)

Comment: Вай плохой - ссылку забыл. Исправляюсь https://yadi.sk/i/XgJc6IoHQhonbw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def clean(col):
    return (col.str.replace(rf'(?:\(|\(\s*)?{col.name}(?:\s*\)|\))?','',flags=re.I)
               .str.replace(r'\s{2,}', ' ')
               .str.strip())

df['name_clean'] = df.groupby('Производитель')['Наименование'].transform(clean)
```

Результат:

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]:
  Артикул            Наименование Производитель        name_clean
0  a0000a1           Розетка GIRA          GIRA           Розетка
1  a0000a2           GiRA розетка          GIRA           розетка
2  a0000a3      Розетка GIRA gira          GIRA           Розетка
3  a0000a4      GIRA розетка gira          GIRA           розетка
4  a0000a5  Розетка GIRA кремовая          GIRA  Розетка кремовая
5  a0000a6                Розетка          GIRA           Розетка
6  a0000a7    Розетка (Gira) gira          GIRA           Розетка
7  a0000a7  Розетка ( Gira ) gira          GIRA           Розетка
```

Исходный DF:

```
In [95]: df
Out[95]:
  Артикул            Наименование Производитель
0  a0000a1           Розетка GIRA          GIRA
1  a0000a2           GiRA розетка          GIRA
2  a0000a3      Розетка GIRA gira          GIRA
3  a0000a4      GIRA розетка gira          GIRA
4  a0000a5  Розетка GIRA кремовая          GIRA
5  a0000a6                Розетка          GIRA
6  a0000a7    Розетка (Gira) gira          GIRA
7  a0000a7  Розетка ( Gira ) gira          GIRA
```

Comment: Благодарю. Уже замучался с решением :-) 
Ваш код помог.